# Preventing an Undefined array entry

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have 2 simple functions that when called either moves one entry back, or one entry forward in the array. However when you get to the end and all of the entries have been shown, there is an additional "undefined" entry. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<?php
$slide_img_array = array();
$slide_desc_array = array();
$slide_name_array = array();

while (!$sql_pres_select->eof()) {
    array_push($slide_img_array, $sql_pres_select->valueof('file_location'));
    array_push($slide_desc_array, $sql_pres_select->valueof('description'));
    array_push($slide_name_array, $sql_pres_select->valueof('slide_name'));
    $sql_pres_select->next();
}
?>
<script>

    var slide_no = 0;
    var slides = <?php echo json_encode($slide_img_array); ?>;
    var desc = <?php echo json_encode($slide_desc_array); ?>;
    var names = <?php echo json_encode($slide_name_array); ?>;

    function nextSlide() {
        if (slide_no < slides.length) {
            slide_no++;
            document.getElementById("display").src = slides[slide_no];
            document.getElementById("func_slide_desc").innerHTML = desc[slide_no];
            document.getElementById("func_slide_name").innerHTML = names[slide_no];

        }

    }
    function prevSlide() {
        if (slide_no > 0) {
            slide_no--;
            document.getElementById("display").src = slides[slide_no];
            document.getElementById("func_slide_desc").innerHTML = desc[slide_no];
            document.getElementById("func_slide_name").innerHTML = names[slide_no];
        }
    }

    function goToSlide(id) {
        slide_no = id;
        document.getElementById("display").src = slides[slide_no];
        document.getElementById("func_slide_desc").innerHTML = desc[slide_no];
        document.getElementById("func_slide_name").innerHTML = names[slide_no];
        document.getElementById('slide_index').innerHTML = slide_no;

    }
</script>
```

I think I need to write a line that checks if whether the end of the array has been reached.But I'm unsure as to how I should do this. I have tried doing the following:

```
function nextSlide() {
            if (slide_no < slides.length) {
                slide_no++;
                document.getElementById("display").src = slides[slide_no];
                document.getElementById("func_slide_desc").innerHTML = desc[slide_no];
                document.getElementById("func_slide_name").innerHTML = names[slide_no];  

            } 
            else if (slide_no===slides.length){
                break;
            }
```

But when I tried that it simply stopped at the first entry and the nextSlide function would no longer work

Comment: try ti remove `else if`  statement and all inside it  at all.

Comment: Also replace `slide_no < slides.length` to `slide_no < slides.length - 1` or increment slide_no++ at the end of commands in if block.

Comment: If I remove the `else if` statement the slides can move back and forth correctly, however the problem is that at the end of the slideshow I get a entry that is undefined, which I don't want

Comment: @andriy I will try that now

Comment: @andriy It worked perfectly thanks! Would you like to add the answer then  I can mark it as correct

Comment: You are welcome, sure i would create answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100446/discussion-between-andriy-ivaneyko-and-albertus-brand-venter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that to access an array element, you need the index to be between 0 to the array length - 1.

In your nextSlide() first implementation you do the following:

```
function nextSlide() {
    if (slide_no < slides.length) {
        slide_no++;
```

which means that when slide_no is equal to length-1 and you call the function, the if() condition will be true because slide_no will be less than slides.length. Then you add 1 to slide_no, which means that slide_no is equal to slides.length now, and you 1 beyond the index limits - this is why you got an undefined value.
I would rewrite it like this

```
function nextSlide() {
    if (slide_no < slides.length - 1) {
        slide_no++;
        document.getElementById("display").src = slides[slide_no];
        document.getElementById("func_slide_desc").innerHTML = desc[slide_no];
        document.getElementById("func_slide_name").innerHTML = names[slide_no];
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, could you maybe just revise the answer for better readability.I almost understand everything, just need a bit more clarity

Comment: !explanations rewritten for clarity based on comment from Albertus.

Comment: Great answer, explained perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `else if` and everything inside it, also also replace `slide_no < slides.length` to `slide_no < slides.length - 1` or move line `slide_no++` to the end of commands in if block.

So it would fix your issue. The problem was in incremention of `slide_no` before accessing `slides` array.

To avoid execution of something you don't need to execute `break` within function, just simply ommit adding any new code ( add  code only into if body) or put `return;` in else statement if you need to stop function from futher execution.